# find all the entire functions that satisfy $|f(z)| \le C^{Im(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all the entire functions that satisfy : 
$$|f(z)| \le C^{Im(z)}$$ 
for a positive $C$

My solution:

I said that if $f(z)$ is entire, then also $e^{-if}$ is entire, and also: 
$h(z)=\frac{f}{e^{-if}}$ is entire. ($|e^{-if}|>0$) then: 
$$|h(z)|=\frac{|f|}{|e^{-if}|}=\frac{|f|}{e^{Im(z)}}<c$$

so according to Liouville h(z) is bounded and entire. so its constant.
if I take the derivative of $h(z)$:

$$h'(z)=\frac{f'e^{-if}+ie^{-if}f}{(e^{-if})^2}=0$$

and from here we get that $f'(z)=0$ and $f(z)=0$.

any comments?

Comment: You have $|\exp(-if(z))|=\exp(Im(f(z))$, not $\exp(Im(z))$

Comment: Hint: Put $m=\log(C)$, $h(z)=\exp(-imz)$ and show that $|f(z)|\leq |h(z)|$ for all $z$.

Comment: @Kelenner thanks. I proved what u wrote. the rest I guess is like I did at the end right? $\frac{f(z)}{h(z)}$ is entire and bounded by 1.

Comment: Right, you can now apply Liouville's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C=e^a$,where $a\in\mathbb R$. We have
$$
|\,f(z)|\le C^{\mathrm{Im}\,z}=|e^{iaz}|
$$
and hence
$$
|\,e^{iaz}f(z)|\le 1.
$$
Thus, by virtue of Liouville's Theorem, $e^{iaz}f(z)$ is constant.

Therefore, $f(z)=ce^{-iaz}$, for some $|c|\le 1$, and $a\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: It will be $|\,f(z)|\le C^{\mathrm{Im}\,z}=|C^{-iz}|$